# App crashes when I try to go to Next Activity Page in App

Tags: java, android, error-handling, logcat

I'm making a pretty basic 6-7 activity app, trying to keep it really simple. I've succesfully added 4 other instances where at the bottom of the app you press "NEXT" and it takes you to the next activity in the app. However, I'm stuck and can't figure out how to continue. I've tried debugging and can't figure out what the error message means. THanks for your help.

The error message from Logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.android.budgeit10.expenses.fourthNext(expenses.java:86)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785) 
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

JAVA:

```
        package com.example.android.budgeit10;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class expenses extends AppCompatActivity {

        AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;
        EditText housingExpense;
        EditText foodExpense;
        EditText transportExpense;
        EditText otherExpense;
        Button expensesButton;
        TextView addExpenses;
        EditText income;

        double housing, food, transport, other, sum;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_expenses);
            housingExpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.housingExpense);
            foodExpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.foodExpense);
            transportExpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.transportExpense);
            otherExpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.otherExpense);
            expensesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.expensesButton);
            addExpenses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalMonthlyExpenses);
            income = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.monthlyIncome);


            expensesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    housing = Double.parseDouble(housingExpense.getText().toString());
                    try {
                        Double.parseDouble(housingExpense.getText().toString());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    }
                    food = Double.parseDouble(foodExpense.getText().toString());
                    transport = Double.parseDouble(transportExpense.getText().toString());
                    other = Double.parseDouble(otherExpense.getText().toString());
                    sum = housing + food + transport + other;
                    addExpenses.setText(Double.toString(sum));

                }
            });

            expensesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(housingExpense.getText().toString()) ||
                            TextUtils.isEmpty(foodExpense.getText().toString()) ||
                            TextUtils.isEmpty(otherExpense.getText().toString()) ||
                            TextUtils.isEmpty(transportExpense.getText().toString())) {

                        addExpenses.setText("Please fill all fields."); // if any of the fields is empty, add nothing to textview

                    } else {
                        Double housing = Double.parseDouble(housingExpense.getText().toString());
                        Double food = Double.parseDouble(foodExpense.getText().toString());
                        Double transport = Double.parseDouble(transportExpense.getText().toString());
                        Double other = Double.parseDouble(otherExpense.getText().toString());
                        Double sum = housing + food + transport + other;
                        addExpenses.setText(Double.toString(sum));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        public void fourthNext(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Goals.class);
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalMonthlyIncome);

            String income = textView.getText().toString();
            startActivity(intent);

        }
```

XML from Button:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.budgeit10.incomePage">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MONTHLY EXPENSES"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalMonthlyIncome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="Enter Monthly Income"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/monthlyIncome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/income_on_expenses"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#2E7D32" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="HOUSING"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/housingExpense"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/housing"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="FOOD"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/foodExpense"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/food"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="TRANSPORTATION"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/transportExpense"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/transport"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="EVERYTHING ELSE"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/otherExpense"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/other"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#2E7D32" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/expensesButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C8E6C9"
            android:onClick="submitOrder"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="TOTAL EXPENSES"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalMonthlyExpenses"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/monthly_expenses"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Extra $ : "
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/extra_cash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/extra_cash"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fourthNext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#C8E6C9"
            android:onClick="fourthNext"
            android:text="NEXT"
            android:textSize="34dp">

        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.budgeit10">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PageTwo" />
    <activity android:name=".incomePage" />
    <activity android:name=".expenses" />
    <activity android:name=".Goals" />
</application>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference` It means that somehow one of your TextView got a null value and when you try to call `getText()` on it, the error pops.

Comment: @A.Omar thanks for responding. Can you point me in the right direction to troubleshoot this and try and figure out one by one which one is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a TextView with id 'totalMonthlyIncome' in your XML layout. (According to the Java code) Just make sure that's there and it will solve the issue.

"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference

at com.example.android.budgeit10.expenses.fourthNext(**expenses.java:86**)"

According to the logcat error is in expenses.java - line 86

Comment: Okay, I added it, still not working. :/ It also sayos unable to find explicit activity class (I made sure it's there) and "Caused by:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

Comment: have you declared your activity in your Manifest xml file ?

Comment: @Naween thanks for your help -- I added the rest of the XML in here to better look at -- The text at line 86 is for a textview FOOD, which isn't attached to any method or anything. Not sure why this would be a problem?

Comment: @A.Omar, yes, so I'm not sure why that's coming up. 

I'll edit my post to include that.

Comment: @Naween, I added the AndroidManifest to the post. Thank you.